# Accessing the query result of the controller in express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

Good day sirs, beginner here at react, express mvc architecture...

i know that this is a react.js community, but i will ask for the server side..

I based by app on the tutorial about creating a express-mysql-react app

Part of the tutorial discussed the creation of mvc architecture, that creates a model that represents the database table, controller for the query connection, and afterwards use the result as an api..i have done the basic goal of the tutorial and i want to expand it.

My goal is to get the result of the findAll() function of the legend.controller.js to my findAll() function of the enrollmentcount.controller.js, because i want to use the query result of the legend controller to the query of the findAll() of enrollmentcount controller.

so far these were the gathered codes

this is the code for enrollmentcount.controller.js

```
const db= require('../models');
const legend = require('./legend.controller.js')
const enrollmentcount = db.enrollmentcount;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

// Retrieve all enrollmentcount from the database.
exports.findAll = (req,res) =>{
    const coursecode = req.query.title;
       //get the query result values from the legend controller...
    const currsemyear = legend.getCurrentYearSem().then(function(result){console.log(result.semester);});
    console.log(currsemyear);
    var condition = coursecode ?{ title: {[Op.like]:`%${coursecode}%`}} : null;



    enrollmentcount.findAll({ where: condition})
    .then(data=>{
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).send({
            message:err.message || "Some error occured while retrieving enrollmentcount. "
        });
    });

};

// Find a single enrollmentcount with an id
exports.findOne= (req,res) =>{

    const id = req.params.id;

    enrollmentcount.findByPk(id)
    .then(data => {res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(
        err=>{
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving enrollmentcount with id=" + id
            });
    });
};
```

legend.controller.js

```
const db= require('../models');
const legend = db.legend;
const Op = db.Sequelize.Op;

function getCurrentYearSem(){
  return  legend.findAll({
        attributes: ['semester', 'schoolyear']
        });
}



exports.findAll = (req,res) =>{

    legend.findAll(
        {
        attributes: ['semester', 'schoolyear']
        })
    .then(data=>{

        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err =>{

        res.send({ message:err.message || "Some error occured while retrieving current semester and current schoolyear. "});
    });

};
```

enrollmentcount.controller.js

```
module.exports = app =>{

    const enrolledcount = require("../controllers/enrollmentcount.controller.js");

    var router = require("express").Router();

    router.get("/",enrolledcount.findAll);
    router.get("/:coursecode",enrolledcount.findOne);


    app.use("/api/enrollmentcount",router);

};
```

legend.routes.js

```
module.exports = app =>{

    const legend = require("../controllers/legend.controller.js");

    var router = require("express").Router();

    router.get("/",legend.findAll);



    app.use("/api/legend",router);

};
```

i'am totaly new in this technology, so sorry and thank you in advance

Comment: are you aware of callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions that I hope will help.

- I suggest adding another layer between your controllers and your database. A common pattern I like to use is controller => service => repository. The controller receives the request, extracts / validates the data that the service needs, invokes the service and returns the results. The service can perform business logic like piecing together data from multiple db calls, data processing, etc. The repository is only responsible for interacting with the database. For example, creating records or loading them.
- If you move the code that loads the data from the database outside the controller, like I describe above, the two controllers can use the service layer to get the data without having to couple the controllers together.
- You need to export the getCurrentYearSem function if you're going to use it in another module.
- cursemyear is a promise that will resolve to the value returned by the getCurrentYearSem function. The code that needs access to the value needs to be in the "then" method or you can use async/await to pause function execution until the value is resolved. In your case, add async before the findall function signature in enrollmentcount.controller.js and then change 'const currsemyear = legend.getCurrentYearSem().then(function(result){console.log(result.semester);});' to 'const currsemyear = await legend.getCurrentYearSem(); Google 'mdn async await' and take a look at the mozilla docs on async/await for more details.
- You don't actually use the cursemyear value anywhere other than the log statement

Here's an abbreviated example to show you what I mean (not tested so you'll have to clean it up a bit):

enrollmentcount.controller.js

```
// Retrieve all enrollmentcount from the database.
exports.findAll = async (req,res) => {
    const coursecode = req.query.title;
    const enrollmentCount = await schoolService.getEnrollmentCount(courseCode);
    res.send(data);
}
```

school.service.js

```
const legendRepo = require('../repositories/legend.repository');
const enrollmentRepo = require('../repositories/enrollment.repository');

exports.getEnrollmentCount = async (courseCode) {
  const currentYearSem = await legendRepo.getCurrentYearSem();
  console.log(currentYearSem);

  const condition = coursecode ? { title: {[Op.like]:`%${coursecode}%`}} : null;

  return enrollmentRepo.getEnrollmentCount(condition);
}
```

legend.repository.js

```
const db= require('../models');
const legend = db.legend;

exports.getCurrentYearSem = () => {
  return  legend.findAll({
    attributes: ['semester', 'schoolyear']
  });
}
```

enrollment.repository.js

```
const db = require('../models');
const enrollmentCount = db.enrollmentcount;

exports.getEnrollmentCount = (condition) => {
  return enrollmentCount.findAll({ where: condition} );
}
```